# Trying to iterate through XML : can't get subnode's values

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml, elementtree

I need to process a huge file with many nodes structured likes this

```
<category name="28931778o.rjpf">
<name>RequestedName</name>
<root>0</root>
<online>1</online>
<description xml:lang="pt-PT">mydescription </description>
<category-links/>
<template/>
<parent name="PTW-0092"/>
<custom-attributes>
<custom-attribute name="sortkey" dt:dt="string">RequestedValue</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="ShortLink" dt:dt="string" xml:lang="pt-PT">/Requested_Url.html</custom-attribute>
<custom-attribute name="ShortLinkActivate" dt:dt="string" xml:lang="pt-PT">true</custom-attribute>
...
</category>
```

I need to get back for each category the 3 requested Values.
I use Python .27 and etree.
when running

```
for elem in tree.iterfind('{http://www.cc.com/a}category'):
    requestedName = elem.find('{http://www.cc.com/a}name').text
    print requestedName
```

It works fine

when running

```
for elem in tree.iterfind('{http://www.cc.com/a}category/{http://www.cc.com/a}custom-attributes/{http://www.cc.com/a}custom-attribute[@name="sortkey"]'):
    print elem.text
```

it works fine also
Problem comes when I want to retreive all three values. I try to find a "category" node and inside it to find the 2 requested values

```
for elem in tree.iterfind('{http://www.cc.com/a}category'):
    requestedName = elem.find('{http://www.cc.com/a}name').text
    print requestedName
    Requestedsortkey = elem.find('./{http://www.cc.com/a}custom-attributes/{http://www.cc.com/a}custom-attribute[@name="sortkey"]')
    print Requestedsortkey.text
    RequestedUrl = elem.find('./{http://www.cc.com/a}custom-attributes/{http://www.cc.com/a}custom-attribute[@name="ShortLink"]')
    print RequestedUrl.text
```

Program crashes with his error message 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Who can help?

Comment: You must check if the object is `None` before you try to access the `text` attribute.

Comment: I'm not sure but I see one difference - in new version you use `./` in path but not with `name`.

Comment: Many thanks to dopstar

Answer (score 0):

You are right Dopstar ! Many thanks

```
for elem in tree.iterfind('{http://www.cc.com/a}category'):
    requestedName = elem.find('{http://www.cc.com/a}name').text
   print requestedName
   Requestedsortkey = elem.find('{http://www.cc.com/a}custom-attributes/{http://www.cc.com/a}custom-attribute[@name="sortkey"]')
    if Requestedsortkey <> None:
       print Requestedsortkey.text
    RequestedUrl = elem.find('{http://www.cc.com/a}custom-attributes/{http://www.cc.com/a}custom-attribute[@name="ShortLink"]')
    if RequestedUrl <> None : 
       print RequestedUrl.text
```